# Transforming large array of objects to csv using json2csv

Tags: node.js, csv, nestjs, json2csv

I need to transform a **large array of JSON** (that can have over 100k positions) into a CSV.
This array is created directly in the application, it's not the result of an uploaded file. 
Looking at the [documentation](https://mircozeiss.com/json2csv/index.html), I've thought on using [parser](https://mircozeiss.com/json2csv/#json2csv-parser-(synchronous-api)) but it says that: 
`For that reason is rarely a good reason to use it until your data is very small or your application doesn't do anything else.` 
Because the data is not small and my app will do other things than creating the csv, I don't think it'll be the best approach but I may be misunderstanding the documentation. 
Is it possible to use the others options ([async parser](https://mircozeiss.com/json2csv/#json2csv-async-parser-(streaming-api)) or [transform](https://mircozeiss.com/json2csv/#json2csv-transform-(streaming-api))) with an already created data (and not a stream of data)?

**FYI**: It's a nest application but I'm using this node.js lib. 
**Update**: I've tryied to insert with an array with over 300k positions, and it went smoothly.

Comment: not so sure that I understand your question? what is current input, I mean what is already provided (JSON file or transformed CSV file)? Where do you want to return? from controller response as a CSV file or raw/plain data?

Comment: My input is provided through datebase's results. Then I created my variable that will store the array of JSON and finally I need to create this csv (with the variable). Later on, I'll send this csv to AWS s3.

Comment: then it is very straight-forward, load from database, transform into CSV file, upload file to S3. what's the problem you face here?

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need any external modules?
Converting JSON into a javascript array of javascript objects is a piece of cake with the native `JSON.parse()` function.

```
    let jsontxt=await fs.readFile('mythings.json','uft8');
    let mythings = JSON.parse(jsontxt);
    if (!Array.isArray(mythings)) throw "Oooops, stranger things happen!"
```

And, then, converting a javascript array into a CSV is very straightforward.
The most obvious and absurd case is just mapping every element of the array into a string that is the JSON representation of the object element. You end up with a useless CSV with a single column containing every element of your original array. And then joining the resulting strings array into a single string, separated by newlines `\n`. It's good for nothing but, heck, it's a CSV!

```
 let csvtxt = mythings.map(JSON.stringify).join("\n");
 await fs.writeFile("mythings.csv",csvtxt,"utf8");
```

Now, you can feel that you are *almost* there. Replace the useless mapping function into your own

```
 let csvtxt = mythings.map(mapElementToColumns).join("\n");
```

and choose a good mapping between the fields of the objects of your array, and the columns of your csv.

```
 function mapElementToColumns(element) {
   return `${JSON.stringify(element.id)},${JSON.stringify(element.name)},${JSON.stringify(element.value)}`;
 }
```

or, in a more thorough way

```
  function mapElementToColumns(fieldNames) {
    return function (element) {
      let fields = fieldnames.map(n => element[n] ? JSON.stringify(element[n]) : '""');
      return fields.join(',');
    }
  }
```

that you may invoke in your map

```
  mythings.map(mapElementToColumns(["id","name","element"])).join("\n");
```

Finally, you might decide to use an automated for "all fields in all objects" approach; which requires that all the objects in the original array maintain a similar fields schema.

You extract all the fields of the first object of the array, and use them as the header row of the csv *and* as the template for extracting the rest of the elements.

```
    let fieldnames = Object.keys(mythings[0]);
```

and then use this field names array as parameter of your map function

```
  let csvtxt= mythings.map(mapElementToColumns(fieldnames)).join("\n");
```

and, also, prepending them as the CSV header

```
 csvtxt.unshift(fieldnames.join(','))
```

---

Putting all the pieces together...

```
function mapElementToColumns(fieldNames) {
  return function (element) {
    let fields = fieldnames.map(n => element[n] ? JSON.stringify(element[n]) : '""');
    return fields.join(',');
  }
}

let jsontxt=await fs.readFile('mythings.json','uft8');
let mythings = JSON.parse(jsontxt);
if (!Array.isArray(mythings)) throw "Oooops, stranger things happen!";
let fieldnames = Object.keys(mythings[0]);
let csvtxt= mythings.map(mapElementToColumns(fieldnames)).join("\n");
csvtxt.unshift(fieldnames.join(','));
await fs.writeFile("mythings.csv",csvtxt,"utf8");
```

And that's it. Pretty neat, uh?